# Accesing youtube video data using"Google APIs Client Library for Java"

Tags: android, api, youtube, google-api-java-client

I am trying to implement an android application that can browse and display youtube content (most importantly thumbnails).

Now normally the way to go would be through the Youtube API and Gdata but unfortunately, they do not play well with Android.

Therefore I have attempted to use the Google APIs Client Library for Java (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

which apparently is fully compatible with Android. Unfortuantely as it is still early in its development there is not much informartion around.

I have managed to succesfully query youtube's database and return data such as titles and descriptions but I am having a lot of trouble returning thumbnails. To be honest, I am not quite sure how the query process works.

here is the main part of the code:

```
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();                  
        final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();      
        final JsonCParser parser = new JsonCParser(jsonFactory);

        HttpRequestFactory factory = transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {

            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
                headers.setApplicationName("1Google-YouTubeSample/1.0");
                headers.gdataVersion = "2";
                request.setHeaders(headers);
                request.addParser(parser);
            }
        });


        YouTubeUrl url = new YouTubeUrl("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos");
        url.author = "whatever";
        url.maxResults = 2;

        HttpRequest request;
        try {
            request = factory.buildGetRequest(url);

            VideoFeed feed = request.execute().parseAs(VideoFeed.class);

            for (Video video : feed.items) {

                Log.v("ddarz", "video URL" + video.player.defaultUrl + "/default.jpg");
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv1.setText(video.title);

                TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                tv2.setText(video.description);

                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL("http://img.youtube.com/vi/bQVoAWSP7k4/1.jpg").getContent());
                //iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

And the classes:

```
public static class VideoFeed {
        @Key List<Video> items;
        int totalItems;
      }

      public static class Video {
        @Key String title;
        @Key String description;
        @Key Player player;
        @Key DateTime updated;
      }

      public static class Player {
        @Key("default") String defaultUrl;
      }

      public static class YouTubeUrl extends GenericUrl {
        @Key final String alt = "jsonc";
        @Key String author;
        @Key("max-results") Integer maxResults;

        YouTubeUrl(String url) {
          super(url);
        }
      }
```

The code is pretty crude but to this point it works, it fails when trying to retrieve the image from the URL.

Does anyone have any insight and/or suggestions on how to best access a video's data (thumbnails etc?) or how in general to go about this problem? Unfortunately youtube access on the Android platform is a seldom spoken of issue.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also stuck at retrieving the video preview thumbnails. Maybe we can try to parse the request for the thumbnails? However, I could only see a gzip compressed request which contains no suitable information :(

Answer (score 2):

You are using the example code from the google api pages. They only cover a few basic elements of a YouTube post. However, you may access much more information when you add this line:

```
url.alt = "jsonc";
```

This way the YouTube API will return all requests in [JSON-C format](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html). You can now extend the class VideoFeed with a new class for the thumbnails. Mine looks like this:

```
public static class Thumbnail {
    @Key("sqDefault")
    String thumbnail_sq;
    @Key("hqDefault")
    String thumbnail_hq;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return thumbnail_sq;
    }
}
```

- sqDefault: 120px*90px
- hqDefault: 480px*360px

For now I'm just returning the standard quality thumbnail. With @Key you can assign variables that the google Api will use to automatically parse them into VideoFeed from the JSON formatted answer to your request. You can use the returned string to download the image and display it in an ImageView.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Worth noting that https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc has the two thumbnails listed as default and hqDefault. This caused me a bit of stress as there is no thumbnail called default. >.<